# SQL (Postgres): Subquery in WHERE clause with IN operator is slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, select, subquery

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
select count(*)
from person p
cross join task t
where t.id in (
    select tp.task_id
    from task_participant tp
    where tp.person_id = p.id )
and p.id = 1234
```

The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS)` generates the following result:

```
Aggregate  (cost=15850181.01..15850181.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=25155.942..25155.943 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..15849814.75 rows=146504 width=0) (actual time=973.619..25155.778 rows=143 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (SubPlan 1)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 286635
        ->  Index Only Scan using personxpk on person p  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = 1234)
              Heap Fetches: 1
        ->  Seq Scan on task t  (cost=0.00..13952.08 rows=293008 width=8) (actual time=0.006..53.361 rows=286778 loops=1)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on task_participant tp  (cost=4.63..103.38 rows=26 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.078 rows=143 loops=286778)
                Recheck Cond: (person_id = p.id)
                Heap Blocks: exact=38705207
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on task_participantx1  (cost=0.00..4.62 rows=26 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=143 loops=286778)
                      Index Cond: (person_id = p.id)
Planning Time: 0.186 ms
Execution Time: 25155.994 ms
```

I don't understand why the sub select is being executed `286778` times. I think that Postgres should execute the subselect only `143` times, because the condition is clear based on the outer query. What am I missing?

EDIT:
It is a generated query. The desired result (and performance) could also be achieved with:

```
select count(*)
from person p
join task_participant tp on tp.person_id = p.id
join task t on t.id = tp.task_id
where p.id = 1234
```

However, I cannot easily rewrite the current query to this better approach. I'm hoping to find a way to achieve a similar execution time without completely changing the query.

Comment: The cross join seems rather strange. What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Yes, I know, it is kind of strange. It is because it is a generated query (I edited the question). The query is selecting all the tasks of a given user. The participation of the user is in the junction table.

Comment: That seems a rather bad query generator then that can't even create a proper JOIN query between two tables. Btw: you don't need the join to the `task` table in the "correct" query - which would make this even more efficient

Comment: You are right. Using just `count(*)`, the `task` join is redundant. And I agree, the query generator is not the best ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
select count(*)
from person p
cross join task t
where EXISTS (
    select NULL
    from task_participant tp
    where tp.person_id = p.id
      AND t.id = tp.task_id )
  and p.id = 1234
```

Comment: This is much faster but returns `286778` instead of 'the desired `143`

Comment: But that query is equivalent. It will have the same result.